# SMS BroadcastReceiver for multiple SMS in android

Tags: android

I am new in Android development and I'm doing an SMS app that receives multiple SMSes i.e notification SMS that's captured into the ListView and another SMS that contains the location of the sender for use in displaying the sender's location on google map.I've managed the first part,how do I listen again for the second SMS using the BroadcastReceiver...In other words how to listen for an incoming SMS when multiple different SMSes are expected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to show us your efforts so we can help you. This is not "give me a code" type of community. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

If you impleted correctly the BroadCastReceiver you shouldnt worry about the second time, it would be fired automatically. You should post your code to have more information.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Android development!
In order to receive incoming SMS's, you need to use the BroadcastReceiver mechanism that listens to incoming SMS's intent.
But, If you want to be sure that the message is going throw your app before it gets into the System's database, you have to give your BroadcastReceiver's Class a high priority on the manifest.

Good Luck.